# How to compile code that have qt6 in mingw64?

Tags: windows, mingw-w64, msys2

I try to use mingw-w64 to compile my code that have qt6 library. but, i get long compile error. for testing my environtment is work. I just try to check qt version.

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    
    std::cout << "Qt version: " << qVersion() << std::endl;
}
```

I installed everything i need with pacman in single line command

```
pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain mingw-w64-x86_64-qt6
```

i think library alraedy settle.

now i try to compile the code with this command

```
g++ version.cpp -o version -I/mingw64/include/qt6/QtCore
-I/mingw64/include/qt6 -I/mingw64/lib/qt6 -lQt6Core -fPIC
```

i get long failed error compile.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: @ssbssa like failed to linking library, so long. this just snippet error. https://pastecode.io/s/bykd9v63. i change my g++ command. `g++ version.cpp -o version -I/mingw64/include/qt6 -I/mingw64/include/qt6/QtCore -fPIC`

Comment: One of the errors says `note: 'std::optional' is only available from C++17 onwards`, so maybe try with `-std=c++17`.

Comment: @ssbssa ok now the error not long anymore with command `g++ gui.cpp -o gui -I/mingw64/include/qt6 -I/mingw64/include/qt6/QtWidgets -std=c++17` but it still produce some error https://pastecode.io/s/801b1vk2

Comment: Now you got linker errors, you didn't add the Qt libraries in the command.